# How to fill an array with a vararg with repeat?

Tags: java

I'm looking for an algorithm to fill an array of a specific size with the contents of a vararg, repeating the last element of the vararg until the array is full.

```
public static <T> T[] fillWithRepeat(int length, T... elements) {
    // make array of length "length" and fill with contents of "elements"
}
```

Does anyone know a good algorithm for this?

Comment: A simple while-loop?

Comment: If you don't want to write the loop yourself, use [Arrays.fill](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(java.lang.Object%5B%5D,int,int,java.lang.Object))

Comment: I always appreciate when users quickly accept answers, even when its not mine ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the algorithm. It also caters for the Generic instantiation problem when you will need to instantiate an array of type `T`

```
public static <T> T[] fillWithRepeat(int length, T... elements) {

    List<T> output = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(elements));
    for(int i = 0; i < length - elements.length; i++){
        output.add(elements[elements.length - 1]);
    }

    return output.toArray(elements);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As the question doesn't include any attempt of solving the problem itself, I assume homework, thus the answer is pseudo code only:

- create a new array *results* of length `length`
- iterate `index` from 0 to `length`
- establish an `index2` variable that runs from 0 to `elements.length`
- assign `ressult[index] = elements[index2]`
- either increase index2, or when it reaches `elements.length-1`, keep it at that value

For creating a "generic" array, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java).

And of course, user Hulk is correct (again), there are utility methods `Arrays.fill()` and for newer Javas `Array.copyOf()` that you should consider using.

Comment: One thing, I can't create an array of a generic type.

Comment: Only the last element in the vararg should be repeated, though.

Comment: @HYBR1D see also [Arrays.copyOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(T%5B%5D,int)) - you want to copy most of the array, and then fill the remainder